# Set Packaged Custom Field as External Id After Initial Deployment

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, isv, externalid

I've been struggling to find a definitive answer as I've seen contradictory information.

In our managed package we have a custom field that we want to make an External Id, but is this possible at all, or is it one of those things where it can be turned on, but can't be turned off?

This document says that it is locked and can't be changed:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm

The last note in this article makes it seem like it is possible - "If the field is part of a managed package, it cannot be marked as External ID unless the package developer makes this change and pushes it. Contact Salesforce Support if you need a Text field part of a managed package indexed in a subscriber org.":
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320036&type=1&mode=1

Then this idea makes it seem like it can't be changed at all, either on or off:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpRLAA0

Is there any official clear documentation on this anywhere?

I saw this related question, but it seems like there was no actual proof behind it and it's a 7 years old so it may have changed: [Make an existing text field an indexed External Id. Will/can Support do it?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14346/make-an-existing-text-field-an-indexed-external-id-will-can-support-do-it)

Comment: The ISVForce guide is better than KB, they are written by Salesforce employees, but not by the doc team, so may contain inaccuracies; Documentation may *also* contain inaccuracies, but this is rare. A "push" is an unusual upgrade path . This out-of-band subscriber-forced update has unique restrictions (e.g. cannot add new components), but can bypass some of the normal rules. See [Push Upgrades](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_push_about.htm) documentation. Try to contact Partner Support for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a definitive answer, no, it is not allowed to make a field that is already in a Managed Package an External Id after it is packaged.  We attempted it and received the following error message:

`Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=[COMPONENT-ID], state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: IsExternalIdentifier Previous Value: false New Value: true`

Where `[COMPONENT-ID]` was the actual Id of the component in our org.